# What is the reason for D407 error raised by Pydocstyle?

Tags: python, docstring

I am using [pydocstyle](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/) and I wonder why it raises the error `D407 / Missing dashed underline after section ('Example')` against my code.

My code looks like this:

```
def foo():
    """
    Function description here...

    Example:
        Some example here...
    """
    # some code here
```

I had similar problem in the past when I tried to add `Note:` section. I wonder whether it is False-Positive error as I am using reStructuredText and I know that pydocstyle sometimes has problems to distinguish reST with Google and numpy styling. Please correct me if I am wrong, but isn't reST related to section `pep257` described under [Default conventions](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/error_codes.html#default-conventions) so I could literally turn off all these checks: D203, D212, D213, ..., **D407**, ...?

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks for the edit. It looks better now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that my hunch was right and D407 is one of errors that is not related to reStructuredText.

`Note:` (same with `Example:`) section is unused in reStructuredText as `..note::` shall be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's means that you need to include a line with `-------` after `Example:` as it shown here https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/rules/dashed-underline-after-section/

In your case:

```py
def foo():
    """
    Function description here...

    Example
    -------
        Some example here...
    """
    # some code here
```